# Check whether the code is running on the GPU or CPU

Tags: c++, cuda

Does anybody know how to check whether the code is running on the GPU or CPU using Cuda?

```
__device__ __host__  double count_something(double variable) {
  if (RUN_ON_GPU) {
    use_cuda_variables();
  } else {
    use_cpu_variables();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no way to *runtime* check which architecture a piece of code is running on, but there is also no need to know, because it can be determined at compile time and handled accordingly. `nvcc` defines several preprocessor symbols which can be used to parse the compilation trajectory while code is being compiled. The key symbol is `__CUDA_ARCH__` which is never defined when compiling host code and always defined when compiling device code.

So it is possible to write a function like this:

```
__device__ __host__ float function(float x)
{
#ifdef __CUDA_ARCH__
    return 10.0f * __sinf(x);
#else
    return 10.0f * sin(x);
#endif
}
```

which will emit different code depending on whether it is compiled for the GPU or host. You can read a more thorough discussion about compilation steering in this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8796369/681865) or in the [C language extensions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#c-language-extensions) section of the CUDA programming guide.

Comment: This is not fully correct. In some cases this code doesn't work - I've spent a lot of time in debugging before I found solution.

Comment: @avtomaton: What isn't correct? How does debugging fit into what is effectively just C++ preprocessor code?

Comment: This is not fully correct. In some cases this code doesn't work - I've spent a lot of time in debugging before I found solution.
`__CUDA_ARCH__` can be defined even in host code, but it is defined to 0 in such case.
Thus proper checking is something like this:
`__device__ __host__ float function(float x)    
{  
#if (defined(__CUDA_ARCH__) && (__CUDA_ARCH__ > 0))  
    return 10.0f * __sinf(x);  
#else  
    // host code here  
#endif  
}`

Comment: `#if (defined(__CUDA_ARCH__) && (__CUDA_ARCH__ > 0))` is definitely the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

I can't add proper code markdown in comments - decided to add full answer.
Using only `__CUDA_ARCH__` define checking is not fully correct. In some cases this code doesn't work - I've spent a lot of time in debugging before I found solution (CUDA documentation haven't any mention about it now).
`__CUDA_ARCH__` can be defined even in host code, but it is defined to 0 in such case.
Thus proper checking is something like this:

```
__device__ __host__ float function(float x)
{
#if (defined(__CUDA_ARCH__) && (__CUDA_ARCH__ > 0))
    // device code here
    return 10.0f * __sinf(x);
#else
    // host code here
    return 10.0f * sin(x);
#endif
}
```